# Compressible Navier-Stokes Equations and Millennium Problems

Tags: fluid-dynamics, navier-stokes

The [4th Clay Institute Millennium Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_existence_and_smoothness) is about the existence and smoothness of the Navier-Stokes Equations. The definition of the problem is limited to the [incompressible fluid equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations#Incompressible_flow). What about [compressible flows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations#Compressible_flow)? Has a similar hypothesis already been proved?